# How to build objects which contain references to the other objects from a stream of CSV data in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I am working on a simple program that moves a character around a series of rooms. I am using a Stream to create the "Room" objects from a CSV file ( *I have stripped room and methods back to highlight my query* ).

In the final object, I want a hashmap that contains a Direction and an associated Room.

CVS file format :

*room-id, room-descr, north, east, south, west*

*Example Kitchen, the kitchen, bathroom, Outside, Lounge,Attic*

My issue is that as I don't know which, if any, of the other room object has been created during the stream. Meaning I need to read the CSV file once storing a dummy map of String, String, then return after the CSV file has been read. Look at a collection of created Rooms, iterate this and create the final intended HashMap of String,Room

```
private  HashMap<Direction,Room> roomexits;
public Room(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}
```

My current reader method looks something like this : -

```
try {
    Path path = Paths.get("src/CSV/map.csv");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    roomsTobeBuilt = reader.lines().map(line -> {
                String[] tempArray = line.split(",");
                Room room = new Room(tempArray[0],tempArray[1]);
                return room;
            }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
}
```

Insert into the stream the creation of the dummy hashmap object.

```
HashMap<String,String> dummy = new HashMap<>(); 
dummy.put("north",tempArray[2]);
dummy.put("east",tempArray[3]);
dummy.put("south",tempArray[4]);
dummy.put("west",tempArray[5]);
```

I would then make a helper method to create the final String,Room HashMap. This feel clunky and longwined. Is there a better way to do this? Can the logic of the stream be controlled in a way to allow for this to be done in the single stream?

Comment: Are all your rooms of equal size? In other words if bathroom's east of kitchen, living room's south of kitchen, and dining room's east of living room, is dining room implicitly south of bathroom? Because if so you could ignore two directions of input and do it as a tree. In other words start from the northeast and just build out.

Comment: the rooms are of equal size,  if you exit north, the room you enter will have an exit south. There will always be between 1 - 4 exits, the CSV file could have null entries for certain directions.  I wouldn't now know the order the rooms are written in the CSV file. So starting in an appropriate  room could be an issue ( regarding tree traversal)

Comment: As long as your file can have forward references, you either need two passes, or some cache of unresolved references that you resolve with each processed line. The latter seems a lot more complicated. Unless you want to split your file into two sections, with room definitions first, then the directional relationships processed second.

Comment: Annoyingly, I cannot edit the CSV input format. A cache sounds interesting but like you say complex, maybe I just look into a two-pass solution.

Comment: You can always store the file contents in memory, you don't literally have to read the file twice (though that's what we'd need to do in the old days with little memory).

Comment: Here's what I'd do. Make the room class with the north, south, east and west objects that also refer to rooms, and which are nullable. So say you load the kitchen and the living room is south. If the LR hasn't been created, create an LR 'stub' with nulls in the east, west and south objects until it is loaded. If the LR has been loaded you'll already have made the kitchen. if a LR 'stub' was created from another room fill in the links. I don't have time write you a fancy stream operation to do that, but at least that way you can do it in one pass, since that's what you seem to want.